# How to get reference to this, when the this is override by calling the method.call(otherObject)?

Tags: javascript

```
    var A = function(x){
        var that = this;
        this.a = x;

    }

    A.prototype = {
            init: function(){
                alert(this.a); // as that is not found :s
            }
    };

    var a = new A(1);
    var b = new A(2)
    a.init.call(b);
    // I want to alert number 1, how to do it?
```

I need this because I use jQuery events.

---

### my sick solution... not so good

I got my question answered but this has some problems, I have to define a local that var and create a closure for every event... sick!

```
        var that = this;
        this.view.skinAppliedSignal.add(function(){
            that.onSkinApplied();
        });
```

// then in the onSkinApplied the this is correct. any way not so hacky to get this done?

Comment: you want to be able to write `alert(that.a)` instead of `alert(this.a)`?

Comment: yes, because the "that = a" and "this = b"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that, in general. The only `this` that exists when a function runs is the `this` established by the invocation.

You can "trap" things in a closure when you establish event handlers:

```
function something() {
  $('.whatever').each(function() {
    var whatever = $(this);
    whatever.find('button').click(function() {
      whatever.hide();
    });
  });
}
```

In that example, "whatever" is used to save the element from the "each" loop so that the event handlers hooked up to button elements can get access to it.

*edit* — Based on a comment and the update to the question, it's clear that perhaps what's desired is something like the ".bind()" function that's part of ES5 (and which is supplied by some libraries, like Prototype, Functional, and jQuery).  By using "bind", you basically wrap any function of your choice up in *another* function, such that your function will always be called with `this` set to some specific object.

Comment: if a closure is made and in that you define a variable to this, then it is available. but this case is more complicated, as the closure can't be made in the prototype because the "that" would be shared by all instances and is not the behaviour I'm looking at.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but that's just the nature of JavaScript.  There's no `this` permanently associated with any particular function.

Comment: take a look at the updated code, if you can improve it. thanks

Comment: Yes something like that is what you can do.  Also in modern browsers, or with the help of some other libraries, you can use a facility to "bind" a function to an object. Those facilities will basically do what you've done, and give you back a reference to the resulting "bound" function.

Comment: thats great, but as I use the same function across many objects is not soo good to use multiple same functions.. or i get it wrong?

Comment: Well you can create as many of those "wrapper" functions as you need; they're not really that expensive. Look up the jQuery "proxy()" routine

Answer (score 1):

Can't be done with a prototype. You could do it this way, however:

```
var A = function(x){
    var that = this;
    this.a = x;
    this.init = function(){
      alert(that.a);
    }
}

var a = new A(1);
var b = new A(2)
a.init.call(b);​
```

Comment: yes, thanks. but this would create a method in the memory for each object I create and I can't afford it.. :s

Comment: Sorry, then there is no solution.